# XML file using C# and data from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

Can we create an XML file using C# and data from SQL Server.

The data in the XML File should look something like, "The temp on `10/10/2012` at `10:10:10 AM` is `76` degrees Fahrenheit"

The date, time and temperature are taken from SQL Server database.
The Query is: `Select Date,Time,IndoorTemp from ThermData`

Do pls help me in getting the code for the above XML File. I have absolute no idea on how to work in C#.

Answer (score 0):

you can use xmlserializer to build the xml file
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
    XmlDocument XD = new XmlDocument();
    XmlNode Root = XD.AppendChild(XD.CreateElement("Root"));
    XmlNode Child = Root.AppendChild(XD.CreateElement("Child"));
    XmlAttribute ChildAtt = Child.Attributes.Append(XD.CreateAttribute("Attribute"));
    ChildAtt.InnerText = "My innertext";
    Child.InnerText = "Node Innertext";
    XD.Save("Add.xml");
```

do something like this.

Comment: Could you give me some reading reference. Because i haven't quite understood your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an XmlWriter to perform the necessary action and use an XmlReader to reference this against an XSD.

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FilePath + FileName))
            {
                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                writer.LookupPrefix("xs");
                writer.WriteStartElement("TestForXML");


                        foreach (DataRow currentRow in dt.Rows)
                        {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("Test");
                            writer.WriteElementString("", Convert.ToString(currentRow[""]));
                            writer.WriteElementString("", Convert.ToString(currentRow[""]));
                            //writer.WriteElementString("", "");
                            writer.WriteElementString("", "");
                        writer.WriteEndElement();

                        }

                    writer.WriteEndElement();   
                writer.WriteEndDocument();

            }

            System.IO.FileInfo f = new System.IO.FileInfo(FilePath + FileName);
            string destinationFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FilePath + f.Name) + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy_HHmmss") + ".xml";
            f.CopyTo (FilePath + destinationFileName);

            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.Schemas.Add(null, FilePath + XSDFile); 
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema; 
            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            document.Load(FilePath + FileName);
            XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(document.InnerXml), settings);
            while(rdr.Read()){}
```